# incompatibility of pdftex graphics driver, expl3 and xparse in TL2022

Tags: pdftex, color, expl3, xparse, output-driver

I am running into a strange compilation error.
Consider the following MWE:

```
% file test.tex
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mdframed}
%\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\input{pdftex.def}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testenv}{s}
   {
     \IfBooleanT{#1}{true}
   }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \begin{testenv}*
    test
  \end{testenv}
\end{document}
```

Trying to compile this gives me

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-29>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[LoadingMPStoPDFconverter(version2006.09.02).]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.136 ...csname newcount\endcsname \scratchcounter
                                                  
?
```

and I have no idea what the problem is.

So how did I run into this? Actually, I tried to use package `mdframed`, which loads package `color` which in turn inputs `pdftex.def` (when processing the document with `pdflatex` as seen in the output.
The `\makeatletter` is necessary since `pdftex.def` is input by the color package.
THe `\ExplSyntaxOn` here is intentional, as in my usecase, I would declare such an environment in some (custom) `expl3` package not relevant in this example.

I tracked down the error to the above MWE. The error goes away by either removing the `\input{pdftex.def}` or the `\ExplSyntaxOn/Off`. Also, `\NewDocumentCommand` seems to work in the above example.

So as I have no idea how this error occurs and at least to me I'd expect the example to work, I am stuck here.
Do I have wrong/missing drivers (not) installed? Or is this some reproducible error in TeXLive?

In case this is relevant: I am running Arch Linux and installed TexLive 2022 using the unix install script. TeXLive is also fully updated (`tlmgr update --all`).

Comment: You're missing the “end part” for `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, so `\ExplSyntaxOff` is taken for it and it's not executed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is due to wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a braced argument for `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, which means `\ExplSyntaxOff` is taken as the argument. This means that `\beg{document} has` \ExplSyntaxOn`, and this then means that some items have the wrong tokenisation of spaces. Fix that, and the issue goes away.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Sorry for that dumb question in this case